# How do I create a body that is fixed in Modelica but it can rotate freely about its centre of gravity?

Tags: object, modeling, modelica, openmodelica

I am looking to model a 3D box in Modelica that rotates freely about its CG. How can I do this?

I tried isolating it into its position on the 3D axes and to apply a torque onto it but I have very rudimentary Modelica skills and am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Find a model blow, which should do what you need:

[image: Rotating Box]

Some description:

- `tau_*` describe scalar time-dependent inputs for the torque around the respective axes `*`.
- `spherical` fixes the positions of the frames `a` and `b` but allows rotation around all three axis
- `bodyBox` is a cuboid which is configured to have its center of gravity in the middle using `r` and `r_shape` (a bit confusing at first)

And the respective code:

```
model RotatingBlock
  "for \"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76051067/how-do-i-create-a-body-that-is-fixed-in-modelica-but-it-can-rotate-freely-about\""

  inner Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.World world annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-50,-10},{-30,10}})));
  Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Joints.Spherical spherical annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-10,-10},{10,10}})));
  Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Parts.BodyBox bodyBox(
    r={-0.1,0,0},
    r_shape={0.1,0,0},
    width=0.2,
    height=0.2) annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{30,-10},{50,10}})));
  Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Forces.WorldTorque torque annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-8,-70},{12,-50}})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Pulse tau_x(
    period=0.4,
    nperiod=1,
    startTime=0.1) annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-52,-46},{-40,-34}})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Constant tau_y(k=0) annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-52,-66},{-40,-54}})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Constant tau_z(k=0) annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-52,-86},{-40,-74}})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Routing.Multiplex3 multiplex3_1 annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-28,-66},{-16,-54}})));

equation 
  connect(spherical.frame_a, world.frame_b)
    annotation (Line(
      points={{-10,0},{-30,0}},
      color={95,95,95},
      thickness=0.5));
  connect(bodyBox.frame_a, spherical.frame_b)
    annotation (Line(
      points={{30,0},{10,0}},
      color={95,95,95},
      thickness=0.5));
  connect(torque.frame_b, bodyBox.frame_a)
    annotation (Line(
      points={{12,-60},{20,-60},{20,0},{30,0}},
      color={95,95,95},
      thickness=0.5));
  connect(multiplex3_1.y, torque.torque) annotation (Line(points={{-15.4,-60},{-10,-60}}, color={0,0,127}));
  connect(tau_x.y, multiplex3_1.u1[1])
    annotation (Line(points={{-39.4,-40},{-34,-40},{-34,-56},{-29.2,-56},{-29.2,-55.8}}, color={0,0,127}));
  connect(tau_y.y, multiplex3_1.u2[1]) annotation (Line(points={{-39.4,-60},{-29.2,-60}}, color={0,0,127}));
  connect(tau_z.y, multiplex3_1.u3[1])
    annotation (Line(points={{-39.4,-80},{-34,-80},{-34,-64},{-29.2,-64},{-29.2,-64.2}}, color={0,0,127}));
  annotation (uses(Modelica(version="4.0.0")));
end RotatingBlock;
```

Comment: Oh that's fantastic! Thanks! So the tau_x acts as the scalar for the torque?

Comment: I have added some description which should help...

Comment: Thanks so much Markus, that clears things up a bit. I was also wondering I was trying to change the tau signals to represent a pulse on each given axis, I would have thought for y, for example, that the tau input into the multiplex would have been u2: [2] and would allow a simultaneous pulse in the y-axis?

Comment: Not sure I got you question correctly, but connecting any non-zero value to `u2` of the mutliplexer will result in a rotation around the y-axis. You can of course combine multiple non-zero inputs for x (=multiplexer.u1), y (=multiplexer.u2) and z (=multiplexer.u3). You can also leave the multiplexer and connect directly to the source, e.g. with `connect(tau_x.y, torque.torque[1])` for the x-axis...

Comment: Thanks Markus! Yeah that actually worked! So I have 3 pulses now that feed directly into the source, which is a torque. This torque then rotates the body as per your last diagram. What I'm trying to do is to be able to spin the body with a certain amount of force, like if you spun a satellite in orbit. How can I specify for the pulses contributing to the Torque what the value of this torque is in Nm?

Comment: The torque in Nm is output by the blocks `tau_*`.

Comment: Is that the same as the pulse? Is tau under Blocks > Math?

Comment: You can use any block from `Modelica.Blocks.Sources`.